# Copy a section of an image and paste it in another?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, copy, paste

Lets say I got two images in VB.NET. Both are 100x100.

Then I want to copy a section of the first image and paste it on the second image.

For example, lets say I want to pickup the rectangle (25,25,75,75) from the first image, and paste it at (25,25) point of the second image.

Sorry, it is hard to explain, so here's an example image:

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like what you are looking for.

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_drawimage_copy_part.html